# calling the first function within a second function that will call the first function

Tags: javascript

I need to call the addPatron function, which will call the validateItems function from within the addpatron function. When i click the addPatron button its supposed to submit the form unless data isnt entered. But I am having trouble because when the button is clicked without adding information I get the error messages but when I enter the information the error message still stays there and the form wont submit. I am not sure if I am calling the addPatron function from the ValidateItem function correctly. please help. Here is the code.

```
var $ = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

var validateItems = function () {
  addpatron()

  var isValid = true

  var firstName = $('firstname').value
  $('firstname').focus() // puts crusor on field

  if (firstName == '') {
    $('firstnameerror').innerHTML = 'Enter First Name'
    isValid = false
  }

  var lastName = $('lastname').value

  if (lastName == '') {
    $('lastnameerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Last Name'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myEmail = $('email').value

  if (myEmail == '') {
    $('emailerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Email'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myCity = $('city').value

  if (myCity == '-') {
    $('cityerror').innerHTML = 'Select a City from the list'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myDonation = $('donation').value

  if (myDonation == '') {
    $('donationerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Donation Amount'
    isValid = false
  } else if (isNaN(myDonation)) {
    $('donationerror').innerHTML = 'Amount must be numeric'
    isValid = false
  }

  return isValid
}

var addpatron = function () {
  var isValid = validateItems

  if (isValid == true) {
    $('myform').submit()
  } else {
    $('endmessage').innerHTML = 'Patron Not Added!'
  }
}

var clearfields = function () {
  firstname.value = ''
  lastname.value = ''
  email.value = ''
  city.value = '-'
  donation.value = ''

  firstnameerror.innerHTML = ''
  lastnameerror.innerHTML = ''
  emailerror.innerHTML = ''
  cityerror.innerHTML = ''
  donationerror.innerHTML = ''
  endmessage.innerHTML = ''
}

window.onload = function () {
  $('validateItems').onclick = addPatron
  $('firstname').focus() // puts the crusor on field
  $('clearfields').onclick = clearfields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `addPatron` in `validateItems`, but you do need to call `validateItems` in `addPatron` :-)

```
var validateItems = function () {
  // addpatron() // don't call this

  var isValid = true

  var firstName = $('firstname').value
  $('firstname').focus() // puts crusor on field

  if (firstName == '') {
    $('firstnameerror').innerHTML = 'Enter First Name'
    isValid = false
  }

  var lastName = $('lastname').value

  if (lastName == '') {
    $('lastnameerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Last Name'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myEmail = $('email').value

  if (myEmail == '') {
    $('emailerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Email'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myCity = $('city').value

  if (myCity == '-') {
    $('cityerror').innerHTML = 'Select a City from the list'
    isValid = false
  }

  var myDonation = $('donation').value

  if (myDonation == '') {
    $('donationerror').innerHTML = 'Enter Donation Amount'
    isValid = false
  } else if (isNaN(myDonation)) {
    $('donationerror').innerHTML = 'Amount must be numeric'
    isValid = false
  }

  return isValid
}

var addpatron = function () {
  var isValid = validateItems() // do call this

  if (isValid == true) {
    $('myform').submit()
  } else {
    $('endmessage').innerHTML = 'Patron Not Added!'
  }
}
```

Comment: the endmessage doesn't show when i click the button to submit the form if not data is entered

Comment: This answer has removed the last two function definitions (`clearfields` and `window.onload`), but I think that was for brevity and those functions should still be included. Did you remove them? Also, are there any error messages in the console? (Press F12 in most browsers.)

Comment: i was told that my $("addpatron").onclick = validateItems; was incorrect because it calls the validateItems function, but i should be calling the addpatron function, which will call the validateItem function from within it

Answer (score 0):

Will Jenkins is correct.

Also, your CSS selectors are wrong. I think your intention is to find html elements with the attributes `id="firstname"`, `id="firstnameerror"`, etc. In CSS selectors, `#` means look up elements by id, so you really wanted `$('#firstname')`, etc.

And it looks like you don't understand jquery. Jquery objects are not the same as the raw DOM elements which are documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API . Raw DOM elements are the lowest-level DOM interface available from browser scripts. Jquery is a library built on top of it. A jquery object represents a DOM element (or more than one element, or maybe none at all). But the methods available on jquery objects are completely different from the ones available on raw DOM elements, which you seem to be trying to use. Note that, since a jquery object can represent no objects at all, jquery will not throw an exception when it encounters a CSS selector which fails to match any elements in the DOM.

There are different ways round this. You could embrace jquery fully, using all the methods available in jquery instead of the ones you've learned. For example, `$('validateItems').onclick = addPatron` would become `$('validateItems').click(addPatron)`. See jquery.com for more details. Or you could use the raw DOM stuff.

You can also mix the two approaches, as long as you don't get confused between the two. For example, I believe that jquery objects can be dereferenced like arrays of raw DOM elements, i.e. `$('#firstname')[0]` will be the first (and only) DOM element with id `firstname`. This means you can treat it like any DOM element; for example, `var firstName = $('#firstname')[0].value`. (Although annoyingly, I can't find this in the documentation.) Conversely, if `element` is a raw DOM element, then `$(element)` is a jquery object containing that element (and no others).

Working with raw DOM elements is unwieldy. The method names are long, and there have been problems with inconsistencies between different browsers (although I suspect that's not as bad as it used to be). Jquery is nicer in my opinion. But jquery is also rather dated now. More modern stuff uses libraries such as React, which uses a different paradigm designed to avoid problems such as forgetting to update parts of the page.